# How to create a file from terminal repeating a set of words infinitely?

Tags: command-line

How to create a file from terminal repeating a set of words infinitely? I need it to create a huge file for parsing purposes like 2-4GB in size. Currently I am manually copying pasting lines into the same file to increase the size.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer working with special unix files, so it wouldn't actually occupy that space. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean something truly infinite like `mkfifo huge.tmp; while true; do yes "a dummy line" > huge.tmp; done`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's an easy way to repeat a line lots of times using the `yes` command:

```
yes we have no bananas | head -n 10000 > out.txt
```

will result in out.txt containing 10,000 lines all saying "we have no bananas".

---

To limit the output to an exact number of bytes, use `head`'s `-c` option instead of `-n`. For example, this generates exactly 10 kB of text:

```
yes we have no bananas | head -c 10000 > out.txt
```

Comment: OP wants to deal with bytes, not lines.

Comment: To specify a limit in bytes, simply use `head -c 10000` for 10 kB instead of `head -n 10000` for 10k lines.

Comment: @ByteCommander yes, but that won't prevent the output from being cut off in the middle of a line. Since the size doesn't have to be precise, I would just figure out the number of lines to get the right size, and round up :)

Comment: I agree, but I am not sure whether that would be a problem either. The OP did not specify which method he wants, but your answer still contains both. Oh, and congrats for doubling your reputation score today :)

Comment: @ByteCommander yep, fair.

Comment: @heemayl OP specified words. The newline character is a byte in length, in any event, and is just as legitimate a byte as any other. Inferred in OP's question is that a newline character is acceptable for their purposes, as they demonstrated by dumping in lines of text.

Answer (score 11):

Perl has the nifty `x` operator:

```
$ perl -e 'print "foo\n" x 5'
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

So, as  a simple solution, you could just write your line a few million times. For example, this command created a 3G file:

```
perl -e 'print "This is my line\n" x 200000000' > file
```

If you need to specify an exact size (2 GiB in this case), you can do:

```
perl -e 'use bytes; while(length($str)<2<<20){ $str.="This is my line\n"} print "$str\n"' > file
```

Comment: If you are patient, you can use cool Perl 6 operators except Perl 6 is much, much, much, much slower :D

Comment: @cat is it really? I haven't touched 6 at all, but I had assumed it'd just have all the perly goodness plus OO extras. Any idea why it's slower?

Comment: My comment was mostly glib, but I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027544/why-are-inline-if-statements-an-average-of-at-least-one-third-slower-than-other) at the beginning of this year that Perl 6 is quite slow, compared to Python 3 which is canonically much slower than Perl 5 (which I didn't test). Work is focused on features and correctness, not performance yet, but it was listed as a goal for 2015. Also, [Is Perl 6 fast enough for me?](http://doc.perl6.org/language/faq#Is_Perl_6_fast_enough_for_me%3F).

Comment: (On the other hand, the list of features is [impressive](https://perl6.org/compilers/features) to say the least.)

Answer (score 10):

I can't recommend *infinitely* repeating text, but you could make a ~2GB file of repeated text with python like so...

```
python3 -c 'with open("bigfile", "w") as f: f.write(("hello world "*10+"\n")*2*10**7)'
```

That will print "hello world " 10 times and make a new line, and repeat that 20,000,000 times, writing the result to the file `bigfile`. If all your chars are ASCII, then each one is one byte, so calculate appropriately depending on what you want to write...

Your cpu may be owned. I run out of RAM if I try doing more than 10,000,000 lines...

<sub>I'm running a toaster though</sub>

Comment: OP wants to deal with bytes, not lines.

Comment: @heemayl of course your answer is better, but I have (vaguely) explained how to calculate how many lines to use to get desired bytes so I don't think my answer is utterly useless

Comment: Also note that, you are opening file with `open()` without closing it explicitly, this could result in unusual situations. Do `close()` or better use a context manager like `with open() ..`.

Comment: @heemayl what makes you so sure the OP wants bytes? The question essentially states that the OP wants a large file. The specific size is very vague (2-4GB), so I really doubt there's a specific byte limit in mind.

Comment: @terdon This: I need it to create a huge file for parsing purposes like 2-4GB in _size_.

Comment: @heemayl yes, but that is very, very vague. My understanding is that the OP just wants a big file and doesn't care about an exact size. Otherwise, they'd have given a size instead of such a huge range of sizes.

Comment: Do you think it will work? I think Python 3 will run out of memory, or worse, cause OOM killer to start killing processes I like, so I won't try it for myself.

Comment: @cat it works up to about `*15000000` on my toaster, and it won't break anything I think because Python throws a Memory Error and gives up at `*20000000`

Comment: @Zanna Amazing, I wouldn't have guessed this.

Comment: @cat ikr! <3python<3

Comment: @heemayl Last I checked, '\n' occupied a byte. So the fact that Zanna created a file including newlines is no more or less valid than any other method. It will still give you a file 2-4GB in size.

Answer (score 7):

- Put the set of words to be repeated in a file e.g. `source.txt`. Get the size of the `source.txt`, in bytes e.g. by:

  ```
   stat -c '%s' source.txt
  ```
- Decide the size of the destination file e.g. `destination.txt`, 2 GB or 4 GB or whatever. Convert the size in bytes.
- Divide the destination file size by source file size.  `bash` can't do floating point arithmetic, but it's not needed in this case.
- Use a `for` construct to repeat a `cat source.txt` operation the division result times. This would be closest approximate of the destination file size you can get by repetition. The output of the operation is saved in `destination.txt`.

For example, assuming the `source.txt` is of 30 bytes, and we want to create a 2 GB file, we need:

```
for ((i=0; i<=((16777216/30)); i++)); do cat source.txt; done >destination.txt
```

Here I am setting upper limit by `((16777216/30))` at initialization time; you can get the result and put it here too.

The operation would take some time; the larger the `source.txt`, the less time will be needed.

Comment: Doesn't this open and close `destination.txt`once for every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @hexafraction Duh, fixed.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a `while`-loop.

Example:
Content of `foo.txt` (This is your source):

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

`bar.txt` is empty (This is your target file). You can now rn the following loop to write the content of `foo.txt` multiple times into `bar.txt`:

```
while [ $(stat --format "%s" bar.txt) -lt 150 ] 
do 
    cat foo.txt >> bar.txt
done
```

Explanation:

- `stat --format "%s" bar.txt` displays the size of `bar.txt` in bytes.
- `while [ $(stat --format "%s" bar.txt) -lt 150 ]` the following actions will be repeated until the target size (in this case 150 bytes) is reached.
- `cat foo.txt >> bar.txt` append the content of `foo.txt` to `bar.txt`

Answer (score 4):

first of fire the command :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.txt bs=2048 count=10
```

will create a file on path of size bs*count random bytes, in our case 2048*10 = 20Kb. that can be changed as per requirement .

```
cat - > file.txt
```

This commands redirects STDIN to a file, so you will need to enter two lines and then press Ctrl+D. Then you will need to run the following command:

```
for i in {1..n}; do cat file.txt file.txt > file2.txt && mv file2.txt file.txt; done
```

Where n is an integer. This will create a file with 2^(n+1) lines in it, by duplicating your original two lines. So to create a file with 16 lines you would do:

```
for i in {1..3}; do cat file.txt file.txt > file2.txt && mv file2.txt file.txt; done
```

Here are some more numbers to get you started:

```
n=15 will give you 65536 lines (if the original two lines were 'hello' and 'world' the file will be 384Kb)
n=20 will give you 2097152 lines (12Mb file with 'hello' and 'world' as the two starting lines)
n=25 will give you 67108864 lines (384Mb file with 'hello' and 'world' as the two starting lines)
```

Comment: OP wants to deal with bytes, not lines.

Comment: OP is also keep coping line for filling  the file . and my first command already created file as per required bytes of memory .

Comment: @heemayl the newline character still occupies a byte, same as my earlier comment. It's a legitimate character. However, the OP did specify *words*, Avani, so I don't think your /dev/urandom technique answers their question.

Comment: It depends on /dev/urandom , whether you are trying some random bytes . Even you can choose your own some files that contains that much bytes of data.

Answer (score 4):

FIFOs are probably what you're looking for. Instead of calling your program with a given file, you can tie the result of a shell command to it via [process subtitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and the program will see its output as a plaintext file. The advantage here is that you are no longer limited by your disk space, so you can reach filesizes that would be impossible otherwise, so long as your program doesn't need to buffer the entire file first and can just parse it line by line. For instance, using @hobbs' reply to generate content :

```
wc -c <(yes we have no bananas | head -n 5000000000)
```

This lends me a 95 gigabytes file (according to wc) at no cost in HDD space and barely any RAM, just enough to buffer what the command returns before it gets read. This is about as close to "infinitely" as you're going to get.